# Is the sql backend right choice for LDAP?

Tags: mysql, ldap, openldap

I have felt some troubles with LDAP dif database after unexpected system reboots. This databse was only read so it is confused why database have had errors.
So im searching for replacement of this database. I think SQL would be more reliable.
What do you think, is it? I need to know how much performance loss i'll meet then. 
How many more IOPS(I/O per second) in percentage I loss too.

Thanks in advance,
skomak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the bdb backend.  SQL will likely be very reliable (assuming an ACID-compliant server), but do you really want to run a whole SQL server just to back your LDAP directory? :)

Comment: Running mysql only for LDAP is bad idea? I was looking for easier direct access to data in database too. But as i mentioned the reliability is my priority. It will be slower but probably with back-ndb clustering no matter. Im very indecisive and I need a hint.
Do you suggest bdb is enough reliable? Is there posibility to cluster it?

Comment: Most places typically cluster entire LDAP servers, using LDAP replication rather than the backend storage. How big is your LDAP database? Unless it's truly massive, it should easily fit in memory on your LDAP server, so I/O shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Pretty much what James said -- I use LDAP replication for my environment because it's proven more than adequate (& can do multi-master clustering relatively easily).  SQL back-ends make sense if your database is obscenely large, but mine is under 20MB for all my sites & the SQL engine would be bigger than storing all that in RAM :)

Comment: Re: reliability, BDB is about as reliable as your underlying filesystem -- I've never had any corruption issues in about 5 years of production LDAP/BDB deployments.  Past performance obviously doesn't guarantee future results, but if you've got at least a pair of servers you're almost certainly well-covered :)

Comment: Thanks you very much for all replies. i have one more question, as you said replication is good choice but what with database corruptions as I have had last time (FS issues)? Well, I still question whether there is an opportunity to complement the replication with failover mode?

Comment: Well, Mirrormode in Openldap supports your requirement. It is more than a master-slave replication, but less than a multi master replication, since it is a requirement taht you point all reads/writes to only one mirror. I have set up that configuration using a hardware LB as well as a ldap proxy. The backend db is hdb.

Comment: Another option is the `syncprov` overlay (which provides master/slave replication) and something like CARP+HADaemon to handle the failover part.  Like Mirrormode all your writes need to go to the "master", but you can read from any synchronized slave (this is how we distribute login accounts in my organization)

Comment: Assume that master fails, your hadaemon routes all requests to slave, which in turn refers all writes to the master. It doesn't make any sense, unless you change the configuration of slave slapd.conf before failing over. That's what mirrormode meant for: 
both nodes are configured as syncrepl providers. A typical set up would be like this with buncha syncrepl consumers and with mirror modes.

http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/dual_dc.png

Comment: @RainDoctor updating & reloading slapd.conf is *why* you would use something like HADaemon (otherwise CARP alone would be sufficient for failover).  I mentioned the simple master/slave + HADaemon solution because it's a less costly option that achieves 90% of the goal -- It is certainly not ideal, but none of the LDAP replication strategies really are...